# dogecoind.exe compilation with mingw

Tags: boost, mingw, daemon, dogecoin-api

I want to compile the dogecoin daemon on Windows (dogecoind.exe) but I get this error:

```
C:\dogecoin-master-1.5\src>mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw 
g++    -c -o json/json_spirit_value.o json/json_spirit_value.cpp
In file included from json/json_spirit_value.cpp:8:0:json/json_spirit_value.h:19:29: fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/config.hpp>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'json/json_spirit_value.o' failed mingw32-make: *** [json/json_spirit_value.o] Error 1
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0). It works for other coins than bitcoin but not doge. Dependancies compilation are ok, I have boost libraries in stage folder and config.hpp in boost folder.

The "official" howto was a simple copy of the [litecoin project](https://github.com/dogecoin/dogecoin/blob/master-1.5/doc/build-msw.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved all files inside json folder in the src root folder, changed for obj/json_spirit_value.o in the make file and it works !